# javascript this refers to same object after ajax callback

Tags: javascript, ajax, closures, this, javascript-objects

I am trying to work with an oauth library for javascript to fetch tweets . I have created an object that takes in the url for the twitter timeline to fetch and puts it in a column. The code is

```
   lister=function(opts) {
    this.setresource =lister.setresource;
    this.config = lister.config;
    this.config.resource = opts;
    this.putTweet = lister.putTweet;
    this.listerstrap = lister.listerstrap;
    this.addStrip = lister.addStrip;
    this.setTweets = lister.setTweets;
    this.addTweets = lister.addTweets;

}
```

Now, if I create two new objects of lister ,

```
    var l1 = new lister('user1'); //user1 and user2 refer to url of the timelines 
    l1.listerstrap();
    var l2 = new lister('user2');
    l2.listerstrap();
```

The listerstrap function is :

```
     lister.listerstrap = function () {
   this.addStrip().setresource().addTweets();

   }
```

The problem happens in addTweets()

```
     lister.addTweets = function () {

   var _ = this;
   oauth.get(twiapi + _.config.resource, function (res) {
       _.setTweets(JSON.parse(res.text));
       console.log(_.config.resource);  // * 
   });
```

At * , the this (_) refers to the same (l2 instance) and hence the tweets from both resources are set into the same column when setTweets is called

Is this a closure problem ?

Edit: I am trying to set tweets  into different columns based on the timeline or lists(as is done in say Tweetdeck , where there is a different column for each list). Though I get the tweets from both urls but they are set into the same column. _ contains the reference to the div element for each column I created in addStrip().  But somehow _ refers to the same instance in the callback . I want it to set the tweets into their respective columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't the `addTweets` method, if you read my previous answer: forget about it.

The problem is this:

```
this.config = lister.config;
this.config.resource = opts;
```

your constructor assigns *a reference* to an object, the object itself *is not copied*. So by assigning a reference to an instance, and then changing *the referenced object*, you're changing the object that is referenced *by all instances*.

The quick fix would be to change `this.config = lister.config;` to something like:

```
this.config = {foo: 'bar', something: 'else', resource: opts};//each time the constructor is called, create a new object literal
```

But please, do look into working with prototypes, because assigning references to properties of the function object, that also doubles as a constructor is not the best approach.

*Update:*

In response to the OP's comment: What you're seeing makes perfect sense. You're creating a new instance, setting the single `config.resource` object (there *is* only one) to `User1`, and the `addTweets` function is invoked. This function performs an **asynchronous** request. *Asynchronous* is something that is all too often overlooked, but very important in this case: before the callback function (that uses the `config.resource` value) is invoked, you create a new instance, and *then* the `config.resource` property is changed. The callback function isn't invoked 'till after the second instance is constructed. That's why the `config.resource` value is changed in that split second between calling `addTweets` and the async callback being invoked, because that's when the second instance is created. It's as simple as that, really.

Comment: Maybe my language was ambiguous , can u take look at the edit of this question . Also, when I check _.config.resource in setresource() , which is called before addTweets() , they are different .. in addTweets() also , _.config.resource is different before the oauth.get() call.... I think the problem is with the oath variable which is the same in both calls

Comment: @karyboy: I've updated my answer - I forgot to mention the async nature of a callback function of a `get` request, but that's why the value of `config.resource` is changed

Comment: Thnx @Elias.My bad .It worked... lost in the complexity of the code , I l try to keep it simple ..

Comment: @karyboy: No worries :-), we've all overlooked things like this... writing the client-side code, and forgetting about async requests has to be one of the most common sources of wasted hours and frustration... Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the `_` refers to different instances. The problem is that you're overwriting properties of the shared config object when you do this:

```
this.config = lister.config;
this.config.resource = opts;
```

So, your `l1` and `l2` always have the very same `config` object. As soon as you instantiate `l2`, it overwrites the `resource` property.

You probably want to create a clone:

```
this.config = clone(lister.config);
```

where `clone` may be some [implementation](http://jsperf.com/cloning-an-object/2) of your choice.

Comment: Maybe my language was ambiguous , can u take look at the edit of this question . Also, when I check _.config.resource in setresource() , which is called before addTweets() , they are different .. in addTweets() also , _.config.resource is different before the oauth.get() call. This means _ refers to different instances before oauth call... I think the problem is with the oath variable which is the same in both calls